# Call local JS package with NodeJS/npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am running NodeJS and have installed the table2csv package via npm

```
 sudo npm install table2csv
```

Now I'm trying to use this package in a web page and I can't work out how to call it correctly, here's my example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--/var/www/node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js-->
    <script src=”node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js”></script>

    <script>function exportCSV(){
        var csv = $("#fullDataTable").table2CSV();
        window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(csv);
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <table id="fullDataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Foo.</th>
              <th>bar.</th>
              <th>bla.</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <Button onclick="exportCSV()">DOWNLOAD</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The full path to the package is `/var/www/node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js` and I have tried variations such as `../node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js` as my web page file is in `/var/www/views`.

(Currently the web page appears correctly but nothing happens when I click the `Download` button)

How do I properly call the package?

------ UPDATE ------

I added a cdn link instead but the function/button still does not appear to be working

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--/var/www/node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table2csv@1.1.3/src/table2csv.min.js"></script>

<script>function exportCSV(){
    var csv = $("#fullDataTable").table2CSV();
    window.location.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=UTF-8,'+ encodeURIComponent(csv);
}
</script>
</head>
```

---- UPDATE 2 ----

Always import JQuery **before** using table2csv!

(the problem still isn't fixed though as the library won't load

---- UPDATE 3 -----

While using a cdn link the console gave me the following errors

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   table2csv.min.js:1` on `<!doctype html>` which seems odd as well as

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).table2csv is not a function
at exportCSV (about:11)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (about:34)
```

on line 11 : `var csv = document.getElementById('fullDataTable').table2csv();`

---- UPDATE 4----

I gave up and just copied the contents of `table2csv.js` into a `<script>` block in my html. Hallelujah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with `npm` you have arrived in a **`module`** world (as opposed to the static script world you're probably used to). Hence the folder where the installed packages reside is named `node-modules`.

Modules generally don't affect the global namespace, which means they do not make anything available to call globally in e.g. an inline event listener like `onclick=""`.

You cannot directly reference any `node_modules` packages from your HTML, that would be a huge security problem as generally `node_modules` is not inside your webroot, and allowing access to files and folders outside your webroot would be extremely unsecure.

You have three options now:

1. Take a deep dive into the world of modules and module bundlers like **webpack**. This will probably take 3 months to understand and use while knowing and understanding what you're doing. If you plan to do heavy Javascript development, there's no way around this.
2. Copy `/var/www/node_modules/table2csv/dist/table2csv.min.js` to you project folder and include it just like your own Javascripts. This has the downside that you will have to do this manually each time you update the package.
3. Find a CDN (Content Delivery Network) that hosts the file you need, and reference it from there.

   ```
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/table2csv@1.1.3/dist/table2csv.min.js" integrity="sha256-O3PXZsVrc25oRq6k38cesC5NsdZOD/tMdjQXEWdaaZU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   ```

Comment: If I use the third option can I still use the "onClick" feature?